# Angular RxJS How to make delay with time came from previous pipe

Tags: angular, rxjs

```
getMessageInSomeTime(): Observable<string> {
    const someAsyncData = {
      text: 'Some text',
      dealyTime: 5000
    };
    return of(someAsyncData).pipe(
      map(response => {
        delay(response.dealyTime); // Here  I have to make pause before return
        return response.text;
      })
    );
  }
```

Now this code has syntax error on delay() pipe call. How to make the code properly?

Comment: Did you try [debouncetime](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/debouncetime)

Answer (score 3):

I believe you're looking for something like this:

```
return of(someAsyncData).pipe(
  switchMap(response =>
    timer(response.dealyTime).pipe(
      mapTo(response.text)
    )
  )
);
```

You want to switch from your observable to a delayed observable which maps to your result. However `delay` is an operator, not an observable so you'd want to use `timer` instead.

Comment: Thank you! But now I got the syntax error on .pipe 
Property 'pipe' does not exist on type 'MonoTypeOperatorFunction<unknown>'.

Comment: @SergeyKudryashov try replacing `delay` with `timer`, then it will work

Comment: @Patrick Good call Patrick, I didn't realize he was using the operator. Thanks